# Apply shadow to a triangle SVG using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering how I could apply shadows to svg images (for example a triangle). I found solutions like polyfill, but it just didn't work the way I wanted it to. I've made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhv1bo0a/) to show you what I would like to give a shadow.

My HTML:

```
<div class="spikes"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.spikes {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBpZD0iTGFhZ18xIiBkYXRhLW5hbWU9IkxhYWcgMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjUgMjUiPg0KICA8ZGVmcz4NCiAgICA8c3R5bGU+DQogIC    AgICAuY2xzLTEgew0KICAgICAgICBmaWxsOiAjZmZmZmZmOw0KICAgICAgfQ0KICAgIDwvc3R5bGU+DQog    IDwvZGVmcz4NCiAgPHRpdGxlPmthcnRlbDwvdGl0bGU+DQogIDxwb2x5Z29uIGNsYXNzPSJjbHMtMSIgcG9pbnRzPSIyNSAxOS43IDI1IDI1IDAgMjUgMCAyMC4yNSAxMi43NyA3LjQ3IDI1IDE5LjciLz4NCjwvc3ZnPg0K");
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1000px;
    transition: 0.75s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px 0px rgba(97,97,97,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px 0px rgba(97,97,97,1);
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px 0px rgba(97,97,97,1);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, it can't be a inline image, as I have to have multiple of those SVG's next to eachother. I know I can calculate the width, and on base of that create the amount images, but I don't like that idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply a shadow to a `background-image` as it's a CSS property and not an element.

What you **can** do is apply a `filter:drop-shadow` to the **element** instead.

Provided the SVG has transparency / alpha it will look something like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.spikes {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBpZD0iTGFhZ18xIiBkYXRhLW5hbWU9IkxhYWcgMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjUgMjUiPg0KICA8ZGVmcz4NCiAgICA8c3R5bGU+DQogICAgICAuY2xzLTEgew0KICAgICAgICBmaWxsOiAjZmZmZmZmOw0KICAgICAgfQ0KICAgIDwvc3R5bGU+DQogIDwvZGVmcz4NCiAgPHRpdGxlPmthcnRlbDwvdGl0bGU+DQogIDxwb2x5Z29uIGNsYXNzPSJjbHMtMSIgcG9pbnRzPSIyNSAxOS43IDI1IDI1IDAgMjUgMCAyMC4yNSAxMi43NyA3LjQ3IDI1IDE5LjciLz4NCjwvc3ZnPg0K");
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1000px;
  transition: 0.75s;
  filter: drop-shadow(-1px -1px 1px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="spikes"></div>
```